# text file contain carriage return between a record

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a text file which contains a table data in , separated format.
there are few rows where line break occur between the record.
is there any why to fix the issue

ex:

```
Date,S.No,Comments

2018-11-10,1,This is line one

2018-11-10,2,this is 

line two

2018-11-10,3,this is line 

three
```

in the above example for second and third data row, line break occurs before it reach the line end and created a new line.

Comment: You are going to need to open the file in an editor that shows you what all the bytes in the file look like.  Sometimes "real" line ends are encoded differently than "wrapped" line ends (Notepad, for example, does this).  Otherwise, you are probably going to have read things in, scanning the data manually and count commas.  It's not going to be fun.

Comment: As I guess, every other row is broken?

Comment: some are broken and some are not.

Comment: Can’t you just read until a new line starts with a date (maybe followed by a comma and a number)?

Comment: assuming you are reading the file line by line, if the line starts with a date, you are reading a new record. Otherwise, the line being read belongs to the current record.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the idea I threw in my comment to your question.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace _53543524_FileWithBrokenRecords
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> records = new List<string>();
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("M:\\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\\53543524_FileWithBrokenRecords\\sampledata.txt"))
            {
                string currentLine = string.Empty;
                bool headerline = true;
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex newRecordSartRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2},");
                while ((currentLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (headerline)
                    {
                        //this handles the header record
                        records.Add(currentLine);
                        headerline = false;
                    }
                    else if (newRecordSartRegex.IsMatch(currentLine))
                    {
                        //this is a new record, so create a new entry in the list
                        records.Add(currentLine);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //this is the continuation on a ongoing record,
                        //so append to the last item in the list
                        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(currentLine))
                        {
                            //add to the current record only if the line is not empty
                            records[records.Count - 1] += currentLine;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (string item in records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The result is this:

```
Date,S.No,Comments
2018-11-10,1,This is line one
2018-11-10,2,this is line two
2018-11-10,3,this is line three
```